# Centering of large font text in TextView

Tags: android

I have an issue, which seems quite trivial, but I have not been able to solve it this far.

I have a full screen landscape activity in which I have a single LinearLayout containing two TextViews which occupy half of the screen each. One of the TextViews shall have a centered character, regardless of font size.

The problem is that when I increase font size of this character it does not center, but instead has its center below the center line of the screen.

Here is the activity with 200sp size character on a 800*480 screen, looks ok - character is centered:

http://i122.photobucket.com/albums/o251/px_seven/char_200_sp.jpg

Here is the activity with 300sp size character, now the character has moved down:

http://i122.photobucket.com/albums/o251/px_seven/char_300_sp.jpg

This is the layout (I change from the default font size 250sp in the code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:keepScreenOn="true">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#000000" /> 

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/tv2"
  android:lines="1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:background="#000000"
  android:text="N"
  android:textSize="250sp" /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Does anybody see what the problem is?

Thanks,
Fredric

Comment: What kind of view do you want to achieve?
Your layout is horizontal but it seems it's vertical in your screenshot

Comment: C.d., the Activity is set to landscape, it is just that the emulator is shown in portrait mode.

Comment: Actually I have tried this code and it looks fine. Letter N is centered in its TextView. Isn't this the kind of view you want to achieve: http://i18.photobucket.com/albums/b122/floatercrop/d0ab407b.png

Comment: C.d., your example works fine because the font size is not big enough to cause a problem (My first screen shot above is also fine because of this)

Comment: I worked a bit more with this yesterday, and it seems Android forces a certain margin from the top of the TextView to the actual character (the big 'N' here). When the 'N' grows big enough, it is pushed down to maintain the margin.

I managed to get a work-around using a negative top margin value for the layout of the TextView (android:layout_marginTop I think it was), to move the entire TextView above the actual screen, but that is really ugly and needs adjustment for different size fonts.

Comment: Surely there must be a robust way to instruct the actual text to be 100% centered in the TextView, regardless of font size..?

Comment: Unfortunately I also wasn't able to find a solution, so I ended up setting a smaller size as the default font size (112sp), and I created a _values-h320dp_ folder, to set the larger (and desired) font size (192sp) for higher screens heights. Testing on various devices and emulators validated this solution for my case, so the character is always vertically centered in my TextView.

Answer (score 19):

Try adding this attribute to your text view `android:includeFontPadding="false"`

Comment: Ah, yes, I did see that attribute. Can't recall if I tried it though - I will have another go tonight, thanks!

Comment: Nope - android:includeFontPadding="false" did not work - in fact it did not change anything. I tried both with android:layout_height="wrap_content" and "match_parent". Any more ideas? :)

Question is if the margin from the char to the view boundary at all can be reduced to zero?

Comment: You can try extending TextView and creating your own TextView. Even though I think there must be a trivial way I couldn't find one.

Comment: Yeah, that might be the way forward. Thanks!

Comment: here you should find the ANSWER http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541196/androidtextview-height-doesnt-change-after-shrinking-the-font-size GL!

Comment: My textView had some letters like y, g. These kind of letters were getting clipped at the bottom. Setting textView with `android:includeFontPadding="false"` helped me to see the text without clipping. Thank you.