# Android:TextView height doesn't change after shrinking the font size

Tags: android, textview

When I click on the button, the font size shrinks to 12.
However, the result is :

[image]

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:background="#80ff0000"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

java:

```
public class FontSizeTestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);




        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                text.setTextSize(12);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How do I shrink the height of the textView so that it only wraps the actual font?

Comment: I just tested your code and it works as it should. Which version of android are you using?

Comment: I tested on Android 3.2 & 4.0

Comment: None of these solutions work for me on any version of Android. T__________T

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I found the reason/solution!!!

This is a known bug for Android 3.1+

[Issue 17343](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17343&can=1&q=textview%20setTextSize%20height&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

[Issue 22493](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22493&can=1&q=textview%20setTextSize%20height&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

Possible workaround are:

```
text.setText(text+"\n");
```

or

```
final String DOUBLE_BYTE_SPACE = "\u3000";
text.setText(text + DOUBLE_BYTE_SPACE);
```

Comment: Great find on the issues. Using the mentioned \u3000 or \u2060 produces a space or a "box" character at the end of the string, depending on the device font. So just appending something is not reliable.

Comment: Moritz's answer is more correct: adding "\u200b" (it does not create a broken box for some devices)

Answer (score 23):

So, After a long search I have found a solution.
Every time you set text do:

```
setText("I am a Text",TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Or after resizing your text just do:

```
setText(getText(),TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: Nice, Accepted Answer

Comment: Very simple, very stupid. Already spent a lot of time (too much I think), but you've saved more...

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using:

```
final String DOUBLE_BYTE_SPACE = "\u3000";
text.setText(text + DOUBLE_BYTE_SPACE);
```

Better use:

```
final String DOUBLE_BYTE_WORDJOINER = "\u2060";
text.setText(text + DOUBLE_BYTE_WORDJOINER);
```

Extra information: Word Joiner is 0 width space.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me while adding "\n" did not do it.

Comment: thanks, why I didn't see this before? Is there any note in android documentation about this?

Comment: That is not really working. Causes 2 Problems. If you right align or center the text you see that "0 Width" is myth on most devices. On a Samsung Galaxy S2 with Android 2.3.3 it came even up as visible rectangle.

Answer (score 3):

I found that adding the character "\u200b" does not appear as a broken character, nor does it add a whitespace/linebreak.

For more details on the "ZERO WIDTH SPACE" see: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm

Comment: Thank you! was struggling with broken characters too but this one works.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe setting the view to View.GONE, changing your text size, then setting to View.VISIBLE would work?

Comment: None of the above answers worked for me, but this did.

Answer (score 1):

try calling invalidate() or a variant of invalidate(). 
From android developer docs:

public void invalidate ()

Since: API Level 1
Invalidate the whole view. If the view is visible, onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called at some point in the future. This must be called from a UI thread. To call from a non-UI thread, call postInvalidate().

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()

Answer (score 0):

In main.xml file TextView size given **android:textSize="40sp"** . and in side java, click on the button change the value here

```
  public void onClick(View v) {

            text.setTextSize(12);
        }
```