# Update item height when modifying text size in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, textview

I have a `ListView` with an `ArrayAdapter` which uses an XML layout, similar to simple_list_item_1, to inflate its content. I have two options in the app menu to increase/decrease the text size. I managed to modify the text size of the `TextViews` inside the `ListView` by overriding the `getView` function of the `ArrayAdapter`. Something like this:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Line>(MyActivity.this, R.layout.line_list, lines){
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, fontSizeDp + zoom);
        return textView;
    }
};
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The menu options change the zoom value and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to make the adapter change the text size.
Until that point everything works.

**The problem is that when I decrease the text size too much, the height of each TextView is not wrapping its content.** That is, the ListView items are too high. When I increase the text size I don't have problems with the items height.

If I call super.getView(position, convertView, parent); with convertView being null, I make the adapter to allways inflate. In that case, decreasing the text size works fine since the height is wrapped. However, I'm causing an overload of work and I don't want that.

I tried invalidating or forcing layout to the listview and/or the textviews but it didn't work.

Any help is appreciated

**EDIT:** This is line_list layout:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:textSize="@dimen/lineTextSize"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingLeft="6dip"
android:paddingRight="6dip" />
```

lineTextSize is 22dp for default and 40dp for large

**EDIT 2:** Look like this [image]

instead of this screen: [image]

Comment: Can you post the `R.layout.line_list` file?

Comment: I had previously tested your code and it works like it should, the `TextView` is wrapping the content of the `TextView` no matter how I modified the size. In my tests `fontSizeDp` was  something constant, like 17 and I simply increased/decreased the `zoom` variable in the `onOptionsItemSelected` callback and then called `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter. How do you modify the size?

Comment: Yes, just like that. In onOptionsItemSelected I change the zoom value and then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). My initial value for fontSizeDp is 40 since I'm testing it on a tablet. When I zoom out at some point the height of the lines is not updated anymore and remain too high

Comment: If you replace `dp` units with `sp` units(like you should have done from the start) for the font size do you see the same behavior?

Comment: Yes, I just tested it but the behaviour is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541196/androidtextview-height-doesnt-change-after-shrinking-the-font-size) that this is a known bug for Android 3.1+

The solution is to add a string like this

```
String ZERO_WIDTH_SPACE = "\u200b";
```

to the text of the TextViews. So, the correct `getView` function of the adapter is:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, fontSizeDp + zoom);
    textView.setText(textView.getText() + ZERO_WIDTH_SPACE);
    return textView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to test the code and it seems the `ListView` doesn't want to update the row's height(when decreasing font size) in `Honeycomb` and above versions. A simple solution to your problem would be to implement the `getView` method of your adapter in such way that it will recreate the row view if you have a decrease in font and/or the recycled view isn't appropriate for the current font size. This is based on your observation, that forcing the `super.getView()` method with `convertView` set as `null` works because the `ListView` will always construct the new row from the ground up. My code is doing something similar only with much better performance:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int mResource;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mResource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
        } else {
            if (mZoom - mOldZoom < 0) {
                Integer cacheZoom = (Integer) convertView.getTag();
                if (cacheZoom == null || cacheZoom.intValue() != mZoom) {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
                    convertView.setTag(mZoom);
                }
            }
        }
        ((TextView) convertView).setTextSize(
                    TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40 + mZoom);
        ((TextView) convertView).setText(getItem(position));
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

`mZoom`, `mOldZoom` are variables with the new and the old zoom value used to see in which direction the font is heading:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.item1:
        mOldZoom = mZoom;
        mZoom += 2;
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        break;
    case R.id.item2:
        mOldZoom = mZoom;
        mZoom -= 2;
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: What is R.layout.adapters_fontchange? If is the same layout as R.layout.line_list, the problem remains (I'm testing on ICS).

Comment: @Ivan `R.layout.adapters_fontchange` is my name for your layout file(it's the same layout). I've tested on `ICS`  and indeed it doesn't work as my initial logic was incorrect. I edited the code from my answer, it should work know as I tested it on a 2.2 device and on two emulators with `Honeycomb`(API 13) + `ICS`(API 14). See how it behaves.

Comment: It works, thanks! There is only one bug but can be fixed by removing ´if (mZoom != 0)´ since if you decrease one and then increase one as mZoom is 0 the size is not set and the text behaves wear because is fighting between a text size of 38 and 40.

Comment: @Ivan You're correct, when I tested I increased/decreased the font in more then one steps and didn't notice it.