# Force TextView to recalculate height

Tags: android, textview

Suppose you have a textview, with it's height set to `wrap_content`:

```
TextView tv;
```

Initially, you set the font size in pixels:

```
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 40);
```

However, something happens, and you need to increase the text size )and therefore the size of `tv`, that's easy:

```
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 50);
```

However, more things happen, and you need to go back to the previous size, it would seem obvious:

```
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 40);
```

This will shrink the font size back to where it was earlier. But the TextView doesn't shrink - ie. it is no longer wrapping content. How do you force it to shrink to the new correct `wrap_content` height?

Comment: Try calling `requestLayout();` or `invalidate();` on the view, does that work?

Comment: see http://pavantilak.blogspot.ie/2012/10/code-to-autoresize-textviewthat.html

Comment: @Sean afraid they don't work ...

Comment: glad to be of help. hope you can find something that's not so complex!

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718831/update-item-height-when-modifying-text-size-in-listview , see if it helps you.