# Android TextView not resized after font size has changed

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

Hi I am trying to have a TextView, it has the following constraints:

1. it can go maximum 2 lines, if it is more than 2 lines, it will just display '...' at the end
2. start with font size 30, we first try to fit everything in one line by reducing to font size from 30 to 12.  that means if we can fit everything with font size 20 in first line, we stick with font size 20
3. if we cannot fit everything with font size 12, we remain at size 12, and we wrap to next line, and everything will remain in size 12

So now I have a EditText, which allows user to type text, and each character user enters, the TextView will reflect what users types, and change in font size accordingly to the rule above.

```
 userEditView.addTextChangedListener(
       new TextWatcher() {
                 @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    float fontSize = 30;
    userTextView.setTextSize(fontSize);
    int userTextViewWidth = userTextView.getWidth();
    int userTextViewContainerWidth = parentRelatievLayOutView.getWidth();//parentRelativeLayout is a RelativeLayout in xml


    // logic here => i want to know when to wrap a line, i should wrap when the textView width is same or greater than the parent container, in such case, we reduce the font size, and then get the new textView width, see if it can be fit in one line or not


      while (userTextViewWidth >= userTextViewContainerWidth) {
        fontSize -= 1;
        if (fontSize <= 12) {
          fontSize = 12;
          break;
        }
        userTextView.setTextSize(fontSize);

        //userTextView.append("\uFEFF"); // does not work
        //userTextView.invalidate(); // does not work
        userTextViewWidth = userTextView.getWidth();// *** this line never gets updated
      }


  }
  @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    userTextView.setText(charSequence);
  }
  @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
  }
});
```

So my problem is `userTextViewWidth = userTextView.getWidth()` never gets updated, i.e. with font size becomes smaller, width is still the same... I want to change that
there is an issue with android where TextView size is not changed [Android:TextView height doesn't change after shrinking the font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541196/androidtextview-height-doesnt-change-after-shrinking-the-font-size) but I tried, none of the techniques it provides worked.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is measure your textView.

instead of

```
userTextViewWidth = userTextView.getWidth();
```

use

```
// find out how wide it 'wants' to be    
userTextView.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, userTextView.getHeight()); 
userTextViewWidth = userTextView.getMeasuredWidth();
```

More info is at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Layout

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:layoutWidth="wrap_content"`, the textview will scale the width size base on text length in it. AFAIK, no way to auto resize textview base on textsize.

Comment: sorry, your solution does not work for my situation.  i have constraints, i need to fit as many characters as i can in a textview that has 2 lines. yes, there might not a direct api in android that help me, this is why i am trying to play with the width.